# How to make template for class and individual object?

Tags: typescript

Im doing simple game with typescript. I want use interface to implement it to class and use it as argument for creating a new class.

```js
interface ObjectConstructor {
    element: HTMLElement;
    x_pos: number;
    y_pos: number;
    x_velocity: number;
    y_velocity: number;
    ele_width: number;
    ele_height: number;
}


abstract class GameObject implements ObjectConstructor {

    element: HTMLElement;
    x_pos: number;
    y_pos: number;
    x_velocity: number;
    y_velocity: number;
    ele_width: number;
    ele_height: number;

    constructor(object: ObjectConstructor) {

        this.element = object.element;
        this.x_pos = object.x_pos;
        this.y_pos = object.y_pos;
        this.x_velocity = object.x_velocity;
        this.y_velocity = object.y_velocity;
        this.ele_width = object.ele_width;
        this.ele_height = object.ele_height;
    }
```

This works without 'implements' statement but when I add it I get the same error as below. But problem appears when i try to make single object with interface variable.

```
//creating player when initialazing new Game instance.
   init(): void {
        this.objects.Player = new Player(PlayerPrototype); //Player inherits from GameObject
    }

}

let PlayerPrototype: ObjectConstructor = {
    element: document.createElement("div"),
    x_pos: Game.bodyWidth/2-30,
    y_pos: Game.bodyHeight-50,
    x_velocity: Game.properites.player_speed,
    y_velocity: Game.properites.player_speed,
    ele_width: 30,
    ele_height: 50
};
```

I get this error from compiler:
**Type '{ element: HTMLDivElement; x_pos: number; y_pos: number; x_velocity: number; y_velocity: number; ele_width: number; ele_height: number; }' is missing the following properties from type 'ObjectConstructor': prototype, getPrototypeOf, getOwnPropertyDescriptor, getOwnPropertyNames, and 18 more.**

Should I use 'Partial<>' statement or use 'type' instead of 'interface'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are getting is that `ObjectConstructor` is a native typescript class

c.f.: [ObjectConstructor](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/interfaces/_node_modules_typedoc_node_modules_typescript_lib_lib_es5_d_.objectconstructor.html)

Try naming your interface something else like `GameObjectConstructorParameters`